# Fastest way to find 16bit match in a 4 element short array?

Tags: c, x86-64, micro-optimization, swar

I may confirm by using nanobench. Today I don't feel clever and can't think of an easy way

I have a array, `short arr[]={0x1234, 0x5432, 0x9090, 0xFEED};`. I know I can use SIMD to compare all elements at once, using `movemask`+`tzcnt` to find the index of a match.  However since it's only 64 bits I was wondering if there's a faster way?

First I thought maybe I can build a 64-bit int by writing `target|(target<<16)|(target<<32)|(target<<48)` but then realized both an AND and SUB isn't the same as a compare since the low 16 can affect the higher 16. Then I thought instead of a plain loop I can write `index=tzcnt((target==arr[0]?1:0)... | target==arr[3]?8:0`

Can anyone think of something more clever? I suspect using the ternary method would give me best results since it's branchless?

Comment: Why do you think the ternary operator is branchless?

Comment: I implemented ternary expressions without a branch by hand????? and godbolt shows me that clang does this without a branch? `return v == 5 ? 1 : v == 8 ? 3 : 99;` Why the heck wouldn't you think a ternary isn't branchless when you're not calling a function?

Comment: Ternary is _not_ branchless. It is _just_ syntactic sugar for `if/else`. The asm code for a ternary has to branch (or, on x86, it might use conditional move (e.g `cmovl`)).

Comment: @Henry I don't see a difference between `return v == 5 ? 1 : v == 8 ? 3 : 99;` and an equivalent version with `if` statements. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h5Mqsx4hz). The fact that a compiler can optimize something to be branchless doesn't mean the statements used are inherently branchless.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Similar to `memchr` or `memcmp`? For something this short I'd say ordinary insts will be fastest. So, code a loop on `short` values. The compiler may automatically use SIMD if appropriate, just like it does for inline/builtin `mem*` functions. The processor will fetch a cache line, so probably no extra memory fetches. Compiler may even code `scasw`

Comment: @Nelfeal I said THIS usage of ternary will be branchless. My question is if there's something more clever I can do so I can help the optimizer out in producing better code. I don't understand your last sentence. This is obviously branchless even if cmov isn't available

Comment: Both `gcc` and `clang` code up 4 `cmp %di` instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SWAR compare-for-equality, the operation you want is XOR, which like SUB produces all-zero on equal inputs, but unlike SUB doesn't propagate carry sideways.

But then you need to detect a contiguous 16 `0` bits.  Unlike `pcmpeqw`, you'll have some zero bits in the other elements.

So it's probably about the same as [https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord) but with wider mask patterns to operate on 16-bit instead of 8-bit chunks.

> There is yet a faster method — use hasless(v, 1), which is defined below; it works in 4 operations and requires no subsquent verification. It simplifies to
>
> ```
> #define haszero(v) (((v) - 0x01010101UL) & ~(v) & 0x80808080UL)
> ```
>
> The subexpression `(v - 0x01010101UL)`, evaluates to a high bit set in any byte whenever the corresponding byte in v is zero or greater than 0x80. The sub-expression `~v & 0x80808080UL` evaluates to high bits set in bytes where the byte of v doesn't have its high bit set (so the byte was less than 0x80). Finally, by ANDing these two sub-expressions the result is the high bits set where the bytes in v were zero, since the high bits set due to a value greater than 0x80 in the first sub-expression are masked off by the second.
>
> This bithack was [originally by](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.c/c/2HtQXvg7iKc/m/xOJeipH6KLMJ) Alan Mycroft in 1987.

So it could look like this (untested):

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

// returns 0 / non-zero status.
uint64_t hasmatch_16in64(uint16_t needle, const uint16_t haystack[4])
{
    uint64_t vneedle = 0x0001000100010001ULL * needle;  // broadcast
    uint64_t vbuf;
    memcpy(&vbuf, haystack, sizeof(vbuf));  // aliasing-safe unaligned load
        //static_assert(sizeof(vbuf) == 4*sizeof(haystack[0]));

    uint64_t match = vbuf ^ vneedle;
    uint64_t any_zeros = (match - 0x0001000100010001ULL) & ~match & 0x8000800080008000ULL;
    return any_zeros;
    // unsigned matchpos = _tzcnt_u32(any_zeros) >> 4;  // I think.
}
```

[Godbolt with GCC and clang](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMQAVlIOAMngMmABy7gBGmMQSABykAA6oCoS2DM5uHt7xickCAUGhLBFRXLGWmNYpQgRMxARp7p4%2BZRUCVTUEeSHhkTEW1bX1GU39HYFdhT0lAJQWqK7EyOwcAKQATADMgchuWADUy%2BuOCgT4ggB0CAfYyxoAgmubDNuuewdHBMSBwBdXN/cbWx2mH2hzwLBYgQ%2BgR%2B62udz%2BAHoEbtiJgCPMGApdhpdsiGAIALQAL0iqF2xyY6IUZz%2BrkhADZJMYCLsEEwFCxKcgEMYuPTAoyIHTBHzmbsgph0PRSLs0JiWcKCKKWWyAJ4U5AAa2WXgAQpIdQARKZ/ZYAdl1f121t2isZYoAbhKpcCDobsaoNF6uF6ND7vb6uHI/H5dgAqcWYSX0A6661I3ZhYioJjoUTHK02rPZnPZhMAcUcjl2AHdCAg5iz0QwvrtUHEbAIsWtVvWbBCSQoW7sCAg8FiiOS%2B1QCAjU%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%2BjDjrBsDU1oYnBVvVA8HQMMpmqrU3p2/8kmAyUGPZTUBdm1HME5BRNWJ6IIBx5AWDiTAAEdibWzHntYjDKLcrmPK8%2ByfIIPyAqCkKdc1SLYSuXYuEsrNnYc73YrNQ0OBmWhOC8XhPA4LRSFQThiwUOYFldDYeFIAhNCjmZNRAdYuDOLwzWiABOSQzXWelokkVYfR8GOOEkeP8%2BTzheAUEBLrzxOo9IOBYCQNATboSJyEoceVvoKJkG2QxgGZYh/3PLAHTwRZurwTASwAeVNhOc5oWgCEiXuIDCTuwkCGpVU4HPx7YQQD4YWhH8H0gsE5IxxG/vgVEFQHSYF7t/TAqhyiuAvk/XgkJPqd0AkmB%2BzgsCdyhCwOBMwCZMGAAoXe%2B8j6MDgTIQQIgxDsCkGQ%2BQSg1Cd10FwfQy8QCmHBvoPAYRe6QBmG2FI4CCQH3WLsAknIFiXHEgZekBJGQEgdKsERhQIQ90%2BuURsngIAOEGJ4Jh/gxgFCKHoBISR1HaKMdkdRnQDGTAsKoloDA2gDBcA0PQzR1GONGPkboxQ%2BjtDMUwiktQrHeIkDMdO8xFihP0LHDu38U4cF2FImRkhZQGCMLsCAHx14qQgLgQgJBVIlymLwAeWgHykAQJgVMPQICF2LvSM4Dcm4aC8GpEu5dK7RLbrwLB/pSAJyTvEnufdc75xmCPKAMBEAoFQBPee08ICz0ngvYAo1Vg/0wFvHee9D7H1IWfC%2BxAr432/nfZgxAv7P1ma/Ag79P6d1/svABScgFqLwKA8BSdIHQNgdweBghEHf2QcQVBGAlhJ0wdgvgBh8GEN2SQv5NCKHiGofwQQigVDqG/rodZaSTBmA4Vw%2BAvCGz8M4II4RoiajcjdEk2RDpKUsGrJgN0RIGCgOIDnNxKR7AMCcM4jIui%2BXBImD44xORUgCp0VkExKQRWGICXY9xIx/G2KsMq9o8qbGBLqFK1xIwtXFDCRnSJXBo4xP6Z3eJiTojSMZLsYAi8A6rDOAo3J%2BAiDEEKWakpYy6nrHWGcANwaQ2hq6e3UgWDJBeDOBoekjJ6Rmi8K0yuXozSWrid3CwIzSlDwmRAMesy55TwoIsotyyUCrNWOsze29MBwuISfXgBzL6UBOUnM5D9SEv0YLcj%2BX8XnayeeC3gryQFgM7t85AMClg5wQa3JOwLQXoO/pCv5OCYUEJ2Y2/ZshkVUOkGi2hmKGHF2YUYVhBLkHcNqcnUlTZyVCMUdSiRho6WSDkRG7ldhNF8tVXorxorzGyoEKq8Vlj9EhMVeqyoKq9XQbea0A1kGgMBLg%2BkaVOrDVRPCZnKJrc44ZsGZwG1dqUmOuQM611GS8meu9cU0Zg9ymtwjVgrwkgziVwDV4YKkga4aErlxphAzeBDOzf3P1pAi4lzLhXautd66N2bl09YsTiMcF9Ux81HBVhqdE1m3N5SOVJDsJIIAA), also including a SIMD intrinsics version.

```
# gcc12.2 -O3 -march=x86-64-v3 -mtune=znver1
# x86-64-v3 is the Haswell/Zen1 baseline: AVX2+FMA+BMI2, but with tune=generic
# without tune=haswell or whatever, GCC uses shl/add /shl/add instead of imul, despite still needing the same constant

hasmatch_16in64:
        movabs  rax, 281479271743489       #    0x1000100010001
        movzx   edi, di                    # zero-extend to 64-bit
        imul    rdi, rax                   # vneedle
        xor     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi]       # match
   # then the bithack
        mov     rdx, rdi
        sub     rdx, rax
        andn    rax, rdi, rdx              # BMI1
        movabs  rdx, -9223231297218904064  # 0x8000800080008000
        and     rax, rdx
        ret
```

Clang unfortunately adds `0xFFFEFFFEFFFEFFFF` instead of reusing the multiplier constant, so it has three 64-bit immediate constants.

AArch64 can do repeating-pattern constants like this as immediates for bitwise ops, and doesn't have as convenient SIMD `movemask`, so this might be more of a win there, especially if you can guarantee alignment of your array of shorts.

---

#### Match position

**If you need to know *where* the match is**, I think that bithack has a `1` in the high bit of each zero byte or u16, and nowhere else.  (The lowest-precendence / last operations are bitwise AND involving `0x80008000...`).

So maybe `tzcnt(any_zeros) >> 4` to go from bit-index to u16-index, rounding down.  e.g. if the second one is zero, the tzcnt result will be 31.  `31 >> 4` = 1.

---

If that doesn't work, then yeah AVX2 or AVX-512 `vpbroadcastw xmm0, edi` / `vmovq` / `vpcmeqw` / `vpmovmskb` / `tzcnt` will work well, too, with **smaller code-size and fewer uops, but maybe higher latency.  Or maybe less.**  (To get a byte offset, right shift if you need an index of which `short`.)

Actually just SSE2 `pshuflw` can broadcast a word to the low qword of an XMM register.  Same for MMX, which would actually allow a memory-source `pcmpeqw mm0, [rsi]` since it has no alignment requirement and is only 64-bit, not 128.

If you can use SIMD intrinsics, especially if you have efficient word broadcast from AVX2, definitely have a look at it.

```c
#include <immintrin.h>

// note the unsigned function arg, not uint16_t;
// we only use the low 16, but GCC doesn't realize that and wastes an instruction in the non-AVX2 version
int hasmatch_SIMD(unsigned needle, const uint16_t haystack[4])
{
#ifdef __AVX2__   // or higher
    __m128i vneedle = _mm_set1_epi16(needle);
#else
    __m128i vneedle =  _mm_cvtsi32_si128(needle);  // movd
    vneedle = _mm_shufflelo_epi16(vneedle, 0);     // broadcast to low half
#endif

    __m128i vbuf = _mm_loadl_epi64((void*)haystack);    // alignment and aliasing safe
    unsigned mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi16(vneedle, vbuf));
    //return _tzcnt_u32(mask) >> 1;
    return mask;
}
```

```
# clang expects narrow integer args to already be zero- or sign-extended to 32
hasmatch_SIMD:
        movd    xmm0, edi
        pshuflw xmm0, xmm0, 0                   # xmm0 = xmm0[0,0,0,0,4,5,6,7]
        movq    xmm1, qword ptr [rsi]           # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
        pcmpeqw xmm1, xmm0
        pmovmskb        eax, xmm1
        ret
```

AXV-512 gives us `vpbroadcastw xmm0, edi`, replacing `vmovd` + `vpbroadcastw xmm,xmm` or `movd + pshuflw`, saving a shuffle uop.

With AVX2, this is 5 single-uop instructions, vs. 7 (or 9 counting the constants) for the SWAR bithack.  Or 6 or 8 not counting the zero-extension of the "needle".  So SIMD is better for front-end throughput.  (https://agner.org/optimize/  / https://uops.info/)

There are limits to which ports some of these instructions can run on (vs. the bithack instructions mostly being any integer ALU port), but presumably you're not doing this in a loop over many such 4-element arrays.  Or else SIMD is an obvious win; checking two 4-element arrays at once in the low and high halves of a `__m128i`.  So probably we do need to consider the front-end costs of setting up those constants.

I didn't add up the latencies; it's probably a bit higher even on Intel CPUs which generally have good latency between integer and SIMD units.

GCC unfortunately fails to optimize away the `movzx edi, di` from the SIMD version if compiled without AVX2; only clang realizes the upper 16 of `_mm_cvtsi32_si128(needle)` is discarded by the later shuffle.  Maybe better to make the function arg `unsigned`, not explicitly a narrow 16-bit type.

Comment: This is the answer I would have written if it weren't already here :-) Alan Mycroft's null-byte finding magic from 1987 (original reference: https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.c/c/2HtQXvg7iKc/m/xOJeipH6KLMJ ) is definitely the first thing to try for these kind of problems.

Comment: Wow, I thought there was going to be a clever answer but I didn't think it'd be this clever. I'll test it out tonight and reread it a few times to make sure I can understand it and hopefully be more clever

Comment: @Henry: Before SIMD was a thing, or on CPUs where it's not good for searching (e.g. because of big stalls when getting data from SIMD to integer regs, like on some ARM CPUs, unlike x86), this kind of SWAR trick was the best way to implement `strlen`, `strcpy`, `memcmp`, and similar loops over byte arrays, doing a whole word at a time.  These techniques are somewhat well-known and still exist in glibc source code.  (including the portable C fallback: [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/57650895)) Welcome to the world of bithacks and SWAR.

Comment: @Henry: Updated with a SIMD version.  It's only 5 uops, vs. 8 for the bithack including the constants.  And tzcnt on its result would give you a byte offset you could use directly (if you can get C to trust you that it's a multiple of 2, e.g. `arr[mask>>1]` probably compiles to a right shift and then scaled-index addressing.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I made this minutes ago too. I'll look over your SIMD. Surprise results! Your code (slightly modified) is the SAME SPEED as my SIMD. Only difference is non simd func is 80 bytes while simd is 48bytes  https://godbolt.org/z/4xc43T76G

Comment: I edited in the 128 bit version so it's more like your code. I then added the results to the end. https://godbolt.org/z/e48ojPv7f mm128 is 32bytes instead of 48. However my real project uses avx2, I hear I shouldn't use 128bit simd in the same functions as 256bit simd?

Comment: @Henry: if you're doing it in a tight loop, obviously you'd want to use SIMD (with `movq` / `movhps` to load two separate 64-bit arrays); it's only worth considering the bithack if you're not doing that.  But then the bithack needs to construct those constants every time, so it's a lot worse for a front-end bottleneck.  Your benchmark has call/ret overhead for a non-inline function, which may be as much of a throughput limit as the code under test.  e.g. https://uica.uops.info/ predicts Skylake will run the SIMD version (with tzcnt/shift) at 2c tput, bottleneck on port 5 from movd+shuffle.

Comment: @Henry: You probably read something about [mixing legacy SSE *asm* with 256-bit AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake).  Compilers avoid any problems with that (even MSVC these days), it's 100% fine to use `__m128i` in programs that use AVX2.  Compilers will use the VEX encoding so there isn't even any legacy SSE for code using `__m128i`, and no need for `vzeroupper` between it and code using `__m256i`.

Comment: @PeterCordes as fun as this was, I guess SIMD will always win unless I find myself in a situation where I ran out of registers/ports

Comment: @Henry: On modern x86, yeah, that's true for this.  On Bulldozer-family, the bithack might have some advantages at least for latency.  Some AArch64 CPUs might benefit from the bithack, though, especially if not doing it in a loop.  (But I think modern AArch64 has efficient SIMD->integer without stalling, for rbit / clz (AArch64 doesn't have tzcnt directly).  It can even horizontally narrow a 128-bit compare result to 64-bit, so you could do 2 4-element arrays at once.  [Convert vector compare mask into bit mask in AArch64 SIMD or ARM NEON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74722950)

Answer (score 1):

Clang with -O2 or -O3 and GCC with -O3 compile a simple search loop into branchless instructions:

```
int indexOf(short target, short* arr) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (target == arr[i]) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WrqofdYTd)

I doubt you can get much better without SIMD. In other words, write simple and understandable code to help the compiler produce efficient code.

Side note: for some reason, neither Clang nor GCC use conditional moves on this very similar code:

```
int indexOf(short target, short* arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (target == arr[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Based on other code I've seen, `gcc` will use conditional moves without any more options if it sees a benefit.

Comment: @CraigEstey See edit. I have no clue why having the array inside the function made GCC not use conditional moves...

Comment: I had done my own test with the array as function scoped and global (vs. argument). It did 4 `cmp` with `je` to four separate return blocks for scoped: `cmp    $0x1234,%di je     L00 cmp    $0x5432,%di je     L01 ... L00: xor    %eax,%eax retq L01: mov    $0x1,%eax retq`

Comment: If I didn't check myself I wouldn't have believed. On x86-64 this is the SAME performance as peters code and simd, HOWEVER on mac it's far slower. Having the array as a global const made both version use cmov https://godbolt.org/z/9aevbr34W

Comment: Strange, now it's about the same when I write my SIMD test. But it looks like it was running on an efficient core before and not one now. I wonder if there's a way I can control that for test

Comment: @Henry: With a global constant array, and a compile-time constant match arg, the checking may optimize away.  Even without actually inlining, GCC inter-procedural optimization (IPA) may figure out that the return value is always false and that there are no side-effects, thus avoiding the call.  Your 0.25ns per call is 1 cycle per iteration on a 4GHz CPU, and we know neither of these versions can actually run that fast (front-end throughput limits, especially if they don't inline and have to set up their scalar constants every time.  Or SIMD port 5 limits on Intel.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I ought to look into nanobench source. *So far* when it says something is faster than something else I've been able to see the improve performance in my real code. However, it is dubious an iteration is .25 ns. I should see if I can find the real margin of error and why it's reporting to be that low. I implemented the SIMD code and saw worse performance, however looking into `perf` I notice it's because the branch predictor was always good since I used repetitive values in my test. I kept the SIMD change and made a note to myself to double check using real code

Answer (score 1):

Here is my addendum to @peter-cordes answer.

> Today I don't feel clever and can't think of an easy way

In that case I would suggest to look at the output of clang or gcc for hint.

If we use the generic code from @Nelfeal above, here is what GCC-13 reports:

```
% gcc-13 -fopt-info-missed -std=c11 -O3 -mavx2 -c generic.c
generic.c:4:21: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
generic.c:2:5: missed: not vectorized: relevant phi not supported: found_14 = PHI <found_5(7), 0(15)>
```

So let's tweak it a bit so as to hint GCC that `found` does not need to be narrowed. Here is what we get now:

```
% gcc-13 -fopt-info-missed -std=c11 -O3 -mavx2 -c generic2.c
-> no more 'missed' statement.
```

We can now have a look at the assembly:

- https://godbolt.org/z/xnGPfr37G
- https://godbolt.org/z/4E3scdEP8
- https://godbolt.org/z/9fYae17oT

Which get us close to Peter's code (clang 17):

AVX2:

```
hasmatch:                               # @hasmatch
        vpmovzxwd       xmm0, qword ptr [rsi]   # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,mem[1],zero,mem[2],zero,mem[3],zero
        vmovd   xmm1, edi
        vpbroadcastd    xmm1, xmm1
        vpcmpeqd        xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
        vpslld  xmm0, xmm0, 31
        xor     eax, eax
        vtestps xmm0, xmm0
        setne   al
        ret
```

SSE42:

```
hasmatch:                               # @hasmatch
        pmovzxwd        xmm0, qword ptr [rsi]           # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,mem[1],zero,mem[2],zero,mem[3],zero
        movd    xmm1, edi
        pshufd  xmm1, xmm1, 0                   # xmm1 = xmm1[0,0,0,0]
        pcmpeqd xmm1, xmm0
        pslld   xmm1, 31
        movmskps        ecx, xmm1
        xor     eax, eax
        test    ecx, ecx
        setne   al
        ret
```

SSE2:

```
hasmatch:                               # @hasmatch
        movq    xmm0, qword ptr [rsi]           # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
        pxor    xmm1, xmm1
        punpcklwd       xmm0, xmm1              # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0],xmm0[1],xmm1[1],xmm0[2],xmm1[2],xmm0[3],xmm1[3]
        movd    xmm1, edi
        pshufd  xmm1, xmm1, 0                   # xmm1 = xmm1[0,0,0,0]
        pcmpeqd xmm1, xmm0
        pslld   xmm1, 31
        movmskps        ecx, xmm1
        xor     eax, eax
        test    ecx, ecx
        setne   al
        ret
```

For the sake of comparison, I added the masking of return value:

- https://godbolt.org/z/68x1chKP6

Kudos to @marc-glisse for hint:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-help/2023-October/142961.html

---

Missed vec:

```
% cat generic.c
#include <stdint.h>
int hasmatch(uint16_t needle, const uint16_t haystack[4]) {
  int found = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    if (needle == haystack[i]) {
      found = 1;
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

no missed vec optimization:

```
% cat generic2.c
#include <stdint.h>
int hasmatch(uint16_t needle, const uint16_t haystack[4]) {
  uint16_t found = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    if (needle == haystack[i]) {
      found = 1;
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

and finally some minor optimization:

```
% cat generic3.c
#include <stdint.h>
int hasmatch(unsigned /*uint_fast16_t*/ needle, const uint16_t haystack[4]) {
  uint16_t found = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    if (needle == haystack[i]) {
      found = 1;
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

Comment: Auto-vectorization is not necessarily better than the scalar bithack, if you're only going to check 8 bytes at a time.  Clang's auto-vectorized asm has multiple wasted instructions: `vpmovzxwd` / `vpslld` are both pointless when it could have simply used `vptest` with a vector constant to check those bits where they were (at the bottom of 16-bit elements), instead of widening and shifting them to the top of dword elements.  Or for a single 64-bit input (not a whole array), `psllw xmm0, 15` / `pmovmskb` and `test eax, 0b10101010`.  Still no need to widen to dword elements with `punpcklwd`

Comment: OTOH, the scalar bithack needed multiple 64-bit constants set up, so it's not great if it's not in a loop.  Portable code that auto-vectorizes acceptably well can be useful for other architectures, and/or if you don't want to clutter the code with x86-specific `#ifdef` and manual vectorization.

Comment: Seems like the first param type is important, see [updated](https://godbolt.org/z/v9jnn9z87).

Comment: Still the same number of back-end uops I think?  But shuffling the array input to widen to dwords in parallel with broadcasting the `needle` does shorten critical path latency vs. doing it after the compare.  And a memory-source `pmovzx xmm` saves a front-end uop (unlike `ymm` on Intel.)  So yeah, you should edit that version into the question.  Also, show the actual C source for people to copy/paste more prominently.  Your answer only contains it in Godbolt links and via a `diff`; the non-diff code block is the old bad version.