Pack high bit of every byte in ARM NEON, for 64 bytes like AVX512 vpmovb2m?
__builtin_ia32_cvtb2mask512() is the GNU C builtin for vpmovb2m k, zmm.
The Intel intrinsic for it is _mm512_movepi8_mask.
It extracts the most-significant bit from each byte, producing an integer mask.
The SSE2 and AVX2 instructions pmovmskb and vpmovmskb do the same thing for 16 or 32-byte vectors, producing the mask in a GPR instead of an AVX-512 mask register.  (_mm_movemask_epi8 and _mm256_movemask_epi8).

I would like an implementation for ARM that is faster than below
I would like an implementation for ARM NEON
I would like an implementation for ARM SVE

I have attached a basic scalar implementation in C.  For those trying to implement this in ARM, we care about the high bit, but each byte's high bit (in a 128bit vector), can be easily shifted to the low bit using the ARM NEON intrinsic: vshrq_n_u8().  Note that I would prefer not to store the bitmap to memory, it should just be the return value of the function similar to the following function.
#define _(n) __attribute((vector_size(1<<n),aligned(1)))
typedef char V  _(6); // 64 bytes, 512 bits
typedef unsigned long U;
#undef _
U generic_cvtb2mask512(V v) {
   U mask=0;int i=0; 
   while(i<64){
     // shift mask by 1 and OR with MSB of v[i] byte
     mask=(mask<<1)|((v[i]&0x80)>>7);
     i++;}
   return mask;
}

This is one possible algorithm for 16 bytes (128b vector), it would just need to be put into a loop for 64 bytes (512b vector):
#define _(n) __attribute((vector_size(1<<n),aligned(1)))
typedef char g4 _(4); // 16 bytes, 128 bits
typedef char g3 _(3); // 8 bytes,   64 bits
typedef unsigned long U;
#undef _

unsigned short get_16msb(g4 v) {
  unsigned short = ret;

  // per byte, make every bit same as msb
  g4 msb = vdupq_n_u8(0x80);
  g4 filled = vceqq_u8(v, msb);

  // create a mask of each bit value
  g4 b = {0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x01, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01,
          0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x01, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01};

  // and vectors together
  g4 z = vandq_u8 (filled,b);

  // extract lower 8 bytes, hi 8 bytes
  g3 lo = vget_low_u8(z);
  g3 hi = vget_high_u8(z);

  // 'or' the 8 bytes of lo together ...
  // put in byte 1 of ret
  // 'or' the 8 bytes of hi together ...  
  // put in byte 2 of ret

  return ret;
}


Are you limited to just NEON, not SVE?  Also, I'd recommend not obfuscating your C with those weird _ macros.  Are you targeting 32-bit ARM only?  If not, please tag [arm64] (as well or instead).

NEON (and AArch64 ASIMD) don't have 512-bit vectors.  IDK if there's anything worth doing differently vs. four separate vector to bitmap operations and combine them with shift/or.  I forget what strategies are good on ARM-32 vs. AArch64, like if there's a narrowing step where we could combine 2 vectors.  AArch64 shrn is excellent if you just want to check the bitmap for non-zero and bit-scan for a set bit (clz or rbit/clz), but if you need an actual mask with 1 bit per element (to e.g. store to memory) you need more work.

For 16 bytes to 16 bits, see SSE _mm_movemask_epi8 equivalent method for ARM NEON .   Not quite a duplicate since I think there is room to combine multiple vectors into one during those reduction steps.  See Convert vector compare mask into bit mask in AArch64 SIMD or ARM NEON? for AArch64 where you get one nibble per byte instead of one bit.

ARM NEON: Convert a binary 8-bit-per-pixel image (only 0/1) to 1-bit-per-pixel? is taking the low instead of high byte, but is doing it for a whole image, many vectors of data, like this where you'd have 4 NEON vectors for 64 bytes.  Using vsli, vector shift-left and insert, and shuffles, to bit-transpose.  That might be more or less a duplicate, except it doesn't mention that __attribute((vector_size(64),aligned(1))) might not compile efficiently on hardware with narrower vectors.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74724385/761288 - this looks promising (128bits to 16bits).  However, I have no idea how to define a function in assembly.

Don't hand-write assembly, use the intrinsics for those instructions.  The intrinsics guide should be searchable by mnemonic. (Hand-written asm is only a good idea if the compiler does a bad job, like for 32-bit ARM if you want to do tricks like using the two d halves of a q register.  There are insert/extract intrinsics that could optimize away, but often don't when you do tricky stuff.  But AArch64 doesn't work that way, each d register is the low half of a separate q, so inline-asm is much more rarely useful.).

SVE should be much easier, although https://gist.github.com/zingaburga/805669eb891c820bd220418ee3f0d6bd#finally-a-pmovmskb-equivalent says there isn't an instruction to copy an SVE predicate to a GPR (because they're variable width depending on the hardware and might be more than 64-bit), so you have to store and reload.  And the minimum hardware width is still only 128-bit, so it might take up to 4 or 2 iterations to do 64 bytes of data.  At least you have narrow enough elements that you have more than 8 even in the minimum-sized vector so separate bytes in memory for storing.

https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2022-April/055021.html appears to be showing asm for vector to integer mask, starting with bext https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0602/2020-12/SVE-Instructions/BEXT--Gather-lower-bits-from-positions-selected-by-bitmask-  instead of testing into a predicate register. Not sure if it only works for taking the low bit; do you need the high bit, or is this like a compare result where all 8 bits of each byte are the same?

Ok, good to know.  Maybe put that in the question.  Along with other important details like whether just storing the bitmap to memory is ok.  bext should actually work for any bit-position, it's like x86 pext so with a different constant the desired bit will still end up in the same place, setting up for the same later sequence of shuffles.

What are you doing with the return value? Like popcount, or clz (count leading zeros)?  Because with SVE it's just one instruction to test into a predicate register (up to the hardware's vector length), but getting that into a GPR integer register is a problem.  If you want to AND or OR multiple bitmaps together, you can do that in predicate registers.  (Or with vectors before movemask).  Since it's inconvenient (costs extra) to do exactly what you're asking for, it's highly relevant what this is part of so you can maybe get the same big-picture result another way.

It's really just a generic function that is needed.  Depending on the application it may be used in different ways.

Well, then some of those use-cases are going to be missing out on optimizations if they insist of having a uint64_t bitmap in a GPR.  Especially with SVE, where there are instructions to e.g. increment an integer register by the popcount or clz/ctz of a predicate register and stuff like that, but not to transfer (the low 64 bits of) a predicate to a GPR.  The max vector width any hardware is allowed to have is 2048 bits, for a predicate width of 256 bits, and I guess they didn't want people to get into the habit of doing things that only work with 64-bit or narrower?

There's a difficulty in wanting to optimise the generic, when most/best optimisations are with the specific. Especially what you want to do with the results.
eg the code for "checking if any high bit is set" can be much cheaper than "check which high bit is set".
  // per byte, make every bit same as msb
  g4 msb = vdupq_n_u8(0x80);
  g4 filled = vceqq_u8(v, msb);

won't make a difference in performance, but it's checking if the sign bit is set, so just do vcltzq_s8(v). i.e. instead of v == 0x80 just check if in signed comparison the value is negative.
If you only care about whether there is a value which has the signed bit set, for Adv SIMD you can just use vpmaxq_s8 on the result of the comparison  and just do:
if (vgetq_lane_s64 (vreinterpretq_s64_s8 (res), 0))
For SVE you don't need this as the compare itself sets flags. You can do ptest on the predicate result of the compare and branch on that. The compiler should be able to remove the ptest during optimization.
If you need which element to use, there are various methods.  As Peter Cordes says in comments, you can use an AND with a special mask and clz for Adv. SIMD.
These patterns are common and are essentially strchr from the standard library.  So for the best sequences I'd recommend checking whatever we have in Arm optimized Routines which we constantly update as we find better ways.
for Neon: https://github.com/ARM-software/optimized-routines/blob/master/string/aarch64/strchr.S is the file and does as above.
for SVE: https://github.com/ARM-software/optimized-routines/blob/master/string/aarch64/strchr-sve.S There's some additional code there as strchr needs to check for the null terminator, but the general idea is the same.
